# Informatica Unconnected Lookup parse error

Tags: lookup, informatica-powercenter

I am calling an unconnected lookup in Informatica and I am getting this error:

```
ERROR : Lookup port rfb_id in lkp_V_CLAIM_ELIGBLTY_EFF_LTCG_seqid not specified in lookup override
.
.
.
Transformation Parse Fatal Error; transformation stopped...
TE_7002 [<<PM Parse Error>> [:LKP.RLKP_V_CLAIM_ELIGBLTY_EFF_LTCG_SEQID(rfb_id)]: : invalid function reference
... >>>>:LKP.RLKP_V_CLAIM_ELIGBLTY_EFF_LTCG_SEQID(rfb_id)<<<<]
```

My lookup is as follows

Ports:

- in_rfb_id [Input]
- rfb_id    [Lookup]
- CLAIM_ELIG_EFF_LTCG_SEQ_ID [Output, Lookup, Return]

SQL Override:

```
select 
   max(CLAIM_ELIG_EFF_LTCG_SEQ_ID) as CLAIM_ELIG_EFF_LTCG_SEQ_ID
from
   $$FAR_CR_VW.V_CLAIM_ELIGBLTY_EFF_LTCG
   -- where rfb_id = in_rfb_id
 group by rfb_id  --
```

Condition:

- rfb_id = in_rfb_id

Other information:

- data types are the same between lookup and expression, both integer
- SQL returns a one column list of 962 integers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SQL Override query has to contain `rfb_id`.

By default, the Integration Service executes a lookup query (automatically generated or provided by the developer) once and stores the result in a cache file. Later, the cache file is queried for every input row. The cache must contain values **both for the output ports** (so they can be returned) **and for the input ports** (so the incoming values can be compared with the cached lookup source based on the lookup condition).

Comment: Thank you. Your changes help even more.

Answer (score 1):

1. Its case sensitive, try to match it.
2. try `lookupOverrideParsingSetting = 2` in custom properties at session level (under config object tab).